# How to avoid overlapping of GameObject without rigidbody?

Tags: unity-game-engine, position, overlapping, rigid-bodies

I was looking for a way to make my gameobject not overlap to the another gameobject but all the solutions are talking about Rigidbody..

when i want to do it in script only without rigidbody, is it possible ? I have a cube with this scale (3,1,1) I make him rotate around itself but i got the overlap problem because his x scale is 3

Is there anyway to make him move and back automatically to avoid the red gameobject?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni7lC.gif)

Comment: it would require some complicated code. why can't you use a rigidbody/collider?

Comment: You will need to make some Raycast calls, a little bit of calculations....

Comment: @ryeMoss, because the rigidbody are pushing the gameobject away only once, without turning him back if there is enough space, same thing with collider.

Comment: Post the code you are using to  rotate that cube

Comment: It's pretty funny if you think about it.  You're not ACTUALLY using a GameEngine at all :)

Comment: i'm using this line to rotate the cube: transform.Rotate (Vector3.up * 1, Space.World);

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method

```js
GameObject myDraggedGO; // parent

     private IEnumerator OverLapChecker(float delay)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
            Collider2D[] colls = new Collider2D[3];
            List<int> nums = new List<int>();
            foreach (var tile in myDraggedGO.GetComponentsInChildren<Rigidbody2D>())
            {
                nums.Add(Physics2D.OverlapCircleNonAlloc(tile.transform.position, 0.5f, colls));
            }
            if (nums.Contains(2))
            {
                myDraggedGO.transform.position = _startpositionOnDrag;
            }
        }
```